# ForeignKey Error at Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

i spend a lot of hours searching for such an error but didn't found anything,
as you know Djangov2.00 requires you to set on_delete=***  with ForeignKey and here i can't do a ForeignKey anymore.
my Models.py

from django.db import models

```
class makereport(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    VID = models.IntegerField()
    Callsign = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    Date = models.DateField(default='yy-mm-dd')
    SelectAward = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=(('1', 'Division Online Day'), ('2', 'Pilot Event'), ('3', 'ATC Event'), ('4', 'Pilot Event')))
    done = models.ForeignKey('reports', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    # reports.ATC = reports.ATC + 1

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name

class reports (models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    VID = models.IntegerField()
    DivisionOnline = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ATCEvent  = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    PilotEvent  = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    PilotSupport  = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ATC = 0
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name
```

and the Error

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: Not Null constraint failed: report_makereport.done_id
```

i don't know what to do with that id ,versions before V2 was working.
Views.py

```
 from django.db import IntegrityError
from django.http import HttpResponse, request
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

# Create your views here.
from django.views import View

from report import models
from report.forms import RepForm
from report.models import makereport, reports


class home(View):
    def get(self,request):
        form = RepForm()
        reps = reports.objects.all()
        rep = makereport.objects.all()
        context = {
            'rep':rep,
            'form' : form,
            'reps':reps
        }
        return render(request,'home.html',context)
    def post(self,request):
        form = RepForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            repo = makereport()
            repo.Name = form.cleaned_data['Name']
            repo.VID = form.cleaned_data['VID']
            repo.Callsign = form.cleaned_data['Callsign']
            repo.Date = form.cleaned_data['Date']
            repo.SelectAward = form.cleaned_data['SelectAward']
            repo.done = None
            try:
                repo.save()
                return  redirect('/')
            except IntegrityError:
                context = {'form':form,
                           'error_msg': 'Error,Please Check your Information'}
                return render(request, 'home.html', context)
        else:
            return self.get(request)
```

Comment: The `ForeignKey` `done` can't remain null or empty

Comment: @Lemayzeur why its eampty?!

Comment: @Lemayzeur i wanna link makereport with reports

Comment: show your view, where you want to create the object

Comment: No i don't wanna create it at view,i just want at done list show of values stores at reports

Comment: as I said to you bellow [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50204206/5644965), `makereport.done` can't remain empty... in this line after `form.is_valid`. `repo = makereport()`.. `repo.done` does not receive any value, so you will always get `Not Null constraint failed: report_makereport.done_id` because this field hasn't been set to receive null value

Comment: so should i add repo.done at views?!i just want at admin when he open "makereport" see a list of all users at "report"

Comment: check my answer: add `on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True` in the field `done` so it can remain empty or null

Comment: i already done that at models.py but do you mean to add it to views?repo.done = on_delete= models.SET_NULL,null=True

Comment: ok, good. try this `repo.done = None` when you create your object

Comment: same problem :"django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: report_makereport.done_id" i will update views.py

Comment: Woooooooow now works

Comment: Thanks mate :D i am stupid Hehehehe repo.done = None Woooow

Comment: did it work, I updated my answer to see how to do it

Comment: Ok! awaesome, glad to be of help.

Comment: Yeah i works :D Thanks a lot but can i ask just one question? if i want to edit number at report class from makereport class what should i do? i tried to type that at "makereport" class ""reports.ATC = reports.ATC + 1""" but it changes for all users at "report" no for one persone?!

Comment: ATC is not a Django Field, are you aware of that? so it's saved nowhere

Comment: Actually i made it like that "ATC  = models.IntegerField(default=0)"

Comment: with that at makereports :      issue = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    if issue is True:
        reports.ATC = reports.ATC + 1

Comment: Actually, Its' possible to assign value to `ATC` from `makereport` through `done` field which has a `ForeignKey` to `reports` model, whereas in your case, done is `None`, so there's no link to it when you had created your object

Comment: what `reports` model stands for? when exactly you create an instance of it? let's continue this conversation in chat

Comment: Good so any reference to know how to link between them to change some values? :D

Comment: Okay in chaat (Y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you set up this field `done = models.ForeignKey('reports', on_delete=models.CASCADE)` means that this field can't remain empty nor null.
When you createe a `makereport` object, this field must have a `report` instance, if not `IntegrityError: Not Null` will raise

In case of creating `makereport` object without a report instance. the following can do it

```
done = models.ForeignKey('reports',
         on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True)
```

in your views, try this:

```
''' codes '''
repo.done = None
repo.save()
```

Comment: Same proplem :/  NOT NULL constraint failed: report_makereport.done_id

Comment: did you set those arguments `models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True` in the field? don't forget `makemigrations` & `migrate`

Comment: Yes i did that and the same problem

Comment: where have you tried to hit the db. to change that an instance? can you show the code?

Comment: ammm i am using sqllite as default,what code you need?

Comment: Done at question